# How to know MIPS-instruction format R, I or J

Tags: assembly, mips, opcode

How to know if the opcode of the MIPS instruction is Register, Imidiate or Jump ?
Given this table from the book, but is there any way to define the format of the opcode ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRn3P.png]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the opcode bits - the most significant 6 bits. In C, if `n` is the 32-bit command dword, the expression for the opcode is `(n >> 26) & 0x3f`.

If opcode is 0, then it's a register command.

If it's 2 (`j`), 3 (`jal`), or 26 (`trap`) - it's a jump.

Else immediate.

A cheat sheet of MIPS encoding, including a list of all opcodes, is available [here](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~isg/res/mips/opcodes), and probably elsewhere.

Comment: i know that the first 6 bits talks about the opcode, and its 64 different ones. From the picture i attached kan you explain litle better ?

Comment: @dwelch i understand the table but what im not ubderstanding is that Seva wrote. his answer is that answer to my quastion but i still need someone to explain it.

Comment: I'm saying that the format of the instruction can be deduced from the `opcode` field. All known opcodes are documented; some correspond to I operatons, some to R, some to J.